# Finding values from template String

Tags: java, string

I am trying to find values of a well defined String. For example:

```
    String template = "From \"{1}\" to \"{2}\".";
    String input = "From \"A\" to \"B\".";
```

The output here would be a String array with the values `["A", "B"]`.

Comment: Split the wring and substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RegularExpression`.

Your template can be represented in Regular Expression: `/From "(.*)" to "(.*)"\./`

In java, you write:

```
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("From \"(.*)\" to \"(.*)\"\\.");
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("From \"A\" to \"B\".");
    if(matcher.find())
    {
        String a = matcher.group(1);
        String b = matcher.group(2);
        return new String[]{a,b};
    }
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just realise I forgot to escape the full stop. You need a \  in the regular expression ( \\ in its Java string) before the full stop to actually match the `.` character. Otherwise it matches any character at the end.